# Combining data from XML file into one row

Tags: c#

I'm working on a website that should pull all of the data from an XML file, and put it in to a table. I have everything working at the moment, but there are a few things that I can't figure out. Right now, the page pulls the data fine, but I would like it to only have one row per email, if that makes sense.

```
Example - 
Name     Email               Total Points
Penny   penny@penny.com        300
Penny   penny@penny.com        200
```

Instead of it showing this, I would like to only have one row for the user `"penny@penny.com"`, and have it combine the total points.

I'm sure some code would help, but I'm not entirely sure what code would be the most helpful, as I didn't make the web service that gets the data, and only wrote a small portion of the actual page.

edit -

The code that pulls the email is -

```
string t7 = rec.SelectSingleNode("email").InnerText;
```

And where it gets placed into the table -

```
    chart += "<tr><td>" + t5 + "</td><td>" + t10 + "</td><td>" + t7 + "</td><td>" + t6 + "</td>" + "<td>" + t8 + "</td><td>" + t9 + "</td><td style=\"border-right:0;\">" + totalpoints + "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Why don't use group by the Email field and Sum on the Total Points field. Linq to XML would be a good solution to you problem. If you could post some code that would be helpful.

Comment: Code part: where you get the data from the webservice untill the output (your question can probably be solved multiple ways, if you provide input to output we could determine what would be easiest/best solution)

Comment: How do you extract the data from the XML file?

Comment: @dwana I've updated the code, I think that should hopefully be enough

Comment: What does your XML look like?

Comment: @ahruss the email is the xml tags <email></email>

Comment: What's the whole person tag look like?

Comment: @ahruss <results><record><location></location><name></name><email></email><totalpoints></totalpoints></record></results>

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy with LINQ. Assuming you've got a list of nodes in `results`, you could do something like this:

```
results.GroupBy(record => record.SelectSingleNode("email").InnerText)
      .Select(group => new Record()
                  {
                       Name = group.First().SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText,
                       Email = group.First().SelectSingleNode("email").InnerText,
                       TotalPoints = group.Sum(record => Convert.ToInt(record.SelectSingleNode("totalpoints").InnerText))
                  });
```

You may also want to consider parsing your XML using [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx). It would make this a little simpler. To do that, you would create a class like this:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType("record")]
public class Record
{ 
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("email")]
    public String Email { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("totalpoints")]
    public int TotalPoints { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could deserialize the list like this (with a `using System.Xml.Serialization`):

```
var results = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Record[]), new XmlRootAttribute("results")).Deserialize(someStream);
```

And this makes the solution to your problem:

```
results.GroupBy(r => r.Email).Select(g => new Record() 
                              {
                                  Name = g.First().Name,
                                  Email = g.First().Email,
                                  TotalPoints = g.Sum(r => r.TotalPoints)
                              });
```

Which isn't much different, but it's a little bit nicer to use, IMO.